# How to pass parameter on jpa query generated by netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpa-2.0

Following is the code generated by netbeans while binding jtable with netbeans gui editor.

```
serverDetailsQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : F1SoftSMSCPUEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM ServerDetails s ");
```

And I changed query using by editing

```
SELECT s FROM ServerDetails s order by id desc
```

this is working fine. Now I want to pass parameter on query to filter record by ShortCode like :

```
SELECT s FROM ServerDetails s where s.shortCode : filterShortCode order by id desc
```

Short code is text field and there is a button which will filter record if user types  shortCode and clicks the button.

**Relevant** code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
    bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

    F1SoftSMSCPUEntityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("F1SoftSMSCPU").createEntityManager();
        serverDetailsQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : F1SoftSMSCPUEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM ServerDetails s order by id desc");
    serverDetailsList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : serverDetailsQuery.getResultList();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    serverDetailsPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    bindButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    bindingDetailsTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
    blockButtonToBindingDetails = new javax.swing.JButton();
    smscBindingDetailsFilterPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    filterByShortCodeTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    smscBindingFilterButton = new javax.swing.JButton();


    }// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.persistence.EntityManager F1SoftSMSCPUEntityManager;
private javax.swing.JButton bindButton;
private javax.swing.JTable bindingDetailsTable;
private javax.swing.JButton blockButtonToBindingDetails;
private javax.swing.JTextField filterByShortCodeTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private java.util.List<com.f1soft.SMSC.entities.ServerDetails> serverDetailsList;
private javax.swing.JPanel serverDetailsPanel;
private javax.persistence.Query serverDetailsQuery;
private javax.swing.JPanel smscBindingDetailsFilterPanel;
private javax.swing.JButton smscBindingFilterButton;
private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
// End of variables declaration
```

Thanks and willing to get response as soon as possible from experts.

Comment: You want a response, but you didn't ask any question.

Comment: I edited question. Now you may understand what is asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to pass a parameter to a query:

```
Query q = em.createQuery(jpql);
q.setParameter("filterShortCode", theParameterValue);
```

EDIT:

the above code should be placed in a listener method, invoked when the button is clicked. It should not be placed in `initComponents()` since obviously, when `initComponents()` is called, the user has not filled the text and clicked on the button yet:

```
smscBindingFilterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String theParameterValue = filterByShortCodeTextField.getText();
        // TODO create and execute the query
    }
}
```

Given your question, I assume that you're not familiar at all with Swing and events in general. I would advise you to forget about NetBeans wysiwyg editor, and practice, with simple examples not involving bindings and JPA. Follow the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), and espacially [the part about events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html).

Comment: I did like your suggestion but showing nullPointerException on this line because this line is written before initialize the JTextField. I know it should be initilize before implement JTextField but netbeans is not allowing me to move neither up this initialization line nor down this parameter set line. Thanks

Comment: Without your code, it's impossible to tell you where it's wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Dear @JB Nizet please [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140385/how-to-make-filterable-to-jtable-record-using-netbeans-ide) and you will understand my requirement.

Comment: I understand your requirement, but I can't tell you where the code is wrong, because I'm not behind your back staring at your screen. Post your code if you want more help.

Comment: Ok, tell me how to post code ? I tried on comment but it is not allowing me to post. Because My code is too large.

Comment: First, only post the **relevant** code. Once you have the relevant code, click the edit link at the bottom of the question, and post the code in the question.