# How to make filterable to jtable record using netbeans ide

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, rowfilter

[image]

There are many rows on above showing jtable. I want to filter record by short code. If I type short code like **1234** it should be display only short code **1234** associated row on jtable.

Thanks

Comment: JTable isn't trivial widget. So, you can't effective use it without read documentation. Small quantity of code isn't variant for not trivial behaviour of JTable. If you don't know base principles of swing then using GUI designers be bad practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have write the code...Start by checking out [how to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), in particular [sorting and filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

The basic requirement would be to attach an `ActionListener` to both the field and button (you can do this from the form editor if you wish).

Within the `actionPerformed` event handler method, you need to create a `RowFilter` and apply it to the tables `RowSorter`.

A table can be configured to automatically create a row sorter by setting the `autoCreateRowSorter` property to `true`.

It's all explained nicely in the linked tutorials...

And another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255282/jtable-sort-rows-based-on-attribute-not-in-table/13258555#13258555)

Comment: @Kalathoki [AFAIK example in tutorial JTextField & JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableFilterDemoProject/src/components/TableFilterDemo.java)

Comment: could be changed to RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text) == case ignore